# Show only the newest messages instead of refreshing the entire div

Tags: php, sql, refresh

I am currently working on a project which involves the Twitter client. I am creating a chatbox where the chat messages get posted to Twitter simultaenously. I am able to display the chat messages in the chat box. However, I wish to only display the new messages instead of refreshing the div every time which basically calls all the messages again. Is there a way where i can just append the new messages to the old messages?

In terms of code, I have a function which puts all the msgs from the sql table into an array and returns it. This array is parsed through and displayed in the div. The div is refreshed.

Any help would be great :)

Comment: Yups. But i am not that good at it. I am currently using javascript for the refresh of the div.

Answer (score 0):

As Kolyaflash said , the solution is in Ajax.
Here's a very simple tutorial of how it works:
http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-php.html?page=1

The main idea is:
Html page with the script , create a "div" for your twitter messages.
The script will call a php file which will generate those messages (API , DATABASE ..)
and then will update the innerHTML of that div.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thansk for the answer! Sorry for the late reply. Will look into it now. Hope i figure this out :)